# Why is the value of p[1] is '0' immediately after entering the for loop?

Tags: python

The python function is here:

```
def rot(p):
    q = p

    print "P val: ", p, "len(p): ", len(p)
    for i in range(len(p)):
        if (i == (len(p)-1)):
            q[0] = p[i]
            print "P val if: ", p, "p(i) : " , p[i]

        else:
            q[i+1] = p[i]
            print "P val else: ", p, "p(i) : " , p[i]


    return q
```

And the output is here:

```
P val:  [0, 1, 0, 0, 0] len(p):  5
P val else:  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0] p(i) :  0
P val else:  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0] p(i) :  0
P val else:  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0] p(i) :  0
P val else:  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0] p(i) :  0
P val if:  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0] p(i) :  0
```

*The question is, why is the list p changing its p[1] value to 0 after entering the for loop?? *

Comment: `print q is p` prints `True`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `q` and `p` reference the same list. Thus any change made to the list through variable `q` will also be reflected in variable `p` because both represent the same underlying list. For example:

```
>>> p = [1, 2, 3]
>>> q = p
>>> q
[1, 2, 3]
>>> q[0] = 0
>>> q
[0, 2, 3]
>>> p
[0, 2, 3]
```

This shows that updates made through `q` are also visible in `p`. This is because `p` and `q` are bound to the same list variable:

```
>>> p is q
True
```

**To fix it**

Work on a *copy* of `p` using slice notation:

```
def rot(p):
    q = p[:]    # copy p
    ...         # rest of your function...


>>> l = [0, 1, 0, 0, 0]
>>> rot(l)
P val:  [0, 1, 0, 0, 0] len(p):  5
P val else:  [0, 1, 0, 0, 0] p(i) :  0
P val else:  [0, 1, 0, 0, 0] p(i) :  1
P val else:  [0, 1, 0, 0, 0] p(i) :  0
P val else:  [0, 1, 0, 0, 0] p(i) :  0
P val if:  [0, 1, 0, 0, 0] p(i) :  0
[0, 0, 1, 0, 0]
>>> l
[0, 1, 0, 0, 0]
```

`l` is unchanged.

Comment: @Dsp No `p` and `q` are variable names which are labels for the same list object.

Comment: @Dsp: it's better to think of them as _names_. A name is bound to some object. Many names can be bound to the same object. Because a list is a mutable object, changes made using one name are also visible through other names that reference the same object. It's the same for other mutable objects such as dictionaries and instances of custom classes. It is similar in concept to C pointers, but the variable are not pointers in that sense.

Comment: Got it! So, slicing comes to rescue when we need to work on a copy of object instead of the object itself. 

Thanks a lot @mhawke and Peter Wood  :)

Comment: @Dsp It's not the slicing, rather you need to make a copy. You could say `q = list(p)`, or using the [**`copy`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/copy.html) module `q = copy(p)`. The slice notation is just a tricky way of doing it.

Comment: @Dsp: as  @PeterWood said. Slicing makes a new copy of the list. `copy()` is more clear in its intent, but it requires an import. Note that slicing doesn't work on _all_ objects, just those that support subscripting. And it only makes sense if the object is mutable, so while it will work on a tuple for example, it won't actually create a new object.

Comment: Also, `copy.copy()` will work on most objects and there is `copy.deepcopy()` which will work on nested objects.